# How can I define integer inputs to a function and get array as an output?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to write a function that takes integer values as an input and gives an array as an output. I have tried the following code but it doesn't show the output result in the serial monitor:

```
int *phi (int cur,int vol,int t) {
  int z[4];
  z[0]=1;
  z[1]=cur;
  z[2]=vol;
  z[3]=t;
//z=cur+vol+t;
  return z;
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {

int result;
result=phi(1,2,5);  
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.print(result);

}
```

Comment: You cannot return an array. What's your final purpose?

Comment: You are asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's purely a programming question.

Comment: If we narrow the scope too much, we end up with nothing but "Did I burn up my Arduino?" and "My PC won't recognize my Arduino" questions. While this is a programming question, Arduinos are all about learning to build and code embedded systems, which means learning programming. We accept questions about using pullups, FET switches, and the lengths of OneWire busses, which strictly speaking, are electronics questions, not Arduino topics either, but are part and parcel of what we do with Arduinos. I vote to reopen the question and perhaps take our guidelines as guides more than lines.

Comment: @EnricBlanco While you can't technically return an array, you can return a pointer to the first element, which is what the function does an often sufficient if you obtain the length by some other means.  However in this case the stack address returned invokes undefined behavior, and the improper assignment of an `int *` return value to an `int` variable strongly suggests the code we're looking at isn't even a version actually tried, but a mid-experiment mishmash.

Comment: **-1 for posting code which does not compile** and claiming that you have tried its behavior, which is not possible.  Your improper assignment of an `int *` to an `int` will be rejected by any sane compiler.  **To receive help you must post the actual code**.

Comment: Just a reminder for everyone to be humble and civil in the comments here. Name calling is strictly not allowed, especially to those that are trying to help others.

Comment: like this: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/passing-arrays-function

Answer (score 3):

Defining the array in phi() returns a pointer to unassigned memory - it is no longer reserved once phi() returns. The next function call or interrupt (which you have no control over) will likely clobber the data.

A better choice would be to define `z` in the caller (loop() in this case) as an uninitialized array and pass it to phi() to fill and return. This is the more usual case, as it:

- avoids using globals,
- permits multiple calls to the function without clobbering previously returned data (you would pass different arrays in this case), and
- it avoids statically defined arrays that may not be needed after the caller returns, in a memory-starved environment (this may not be applicable if loop() is the caller).

In short, it gives the calling function the greatest flexibility, while committing the least amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have created an array which only has scope with in the method "phi".

In practical terms, the array "z" is a local variable declared inside of the method and, as such, will likely end up in temporary RAM.  When the method has completed, the RAM reserved for that method's local variables is released and is available for other purposes.

To fix this you could make "z" a static or you could give "z" global scope.

Comment: There are some other problems you need to sort through.  Like mixing "integers" and "pointers to integers".  But the problem addressed by the above answer is usually the one that causes people the most confusion / problems.